# setDates array format not working

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap-datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

I want to set dates dynamically on button click. Here is the response what I get from the function:

```
var result = ['2016-12-05','2016-12-12','2016-12-19','2016-12-26','2016-12-06','2016-12-13','2016-12-20','2016-12-27'
,'2016-12-07','2016-12-14','2016-12-21','2016-12-28','2016-12-01','2016-12-08','2016-12-15','2016-12-22'
,'2016-12-29','2016-12-02','2016-12-09','2016-12-16','2016-12-23','2016-12-30','2016-12-03','2016-12-10'
,'2016-12-17','2016-12-24','2016-12-31','2016-12-04','2016-12-11','2016-12-18','2016-12-25']
```

If I put above response manually then it works perfectly, but on click of a button it is not working.

If I pass dates from Ajax then it automatically adds `"` like below:

```
"'2016-12-05','2016-12-12','2016-12-19','2016-12-26','2016-12-06','2016-12-13','2016-12-20','2016-12-27','2016-12-07','2016-12-14','2016-12-21','2016-12-28','2016-12-01','2016-12-08','2016-12-15','2016-12-22','2016-12-29','2016-12-02','2016-12-09','2016-12-16','2016-12-23','2016-12-30','2016-12-03','2016-12-10','2016-12-17','2016-12-24','2016-12-31','2016-12-04','2016-12-11','2016-12-18','2016-12-25'"
```

Here is the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {month:selected_month},
    url: 'http://test.com/v/get_data',
    success: function(result) {
        var day_of_week = [result];
        $('#spotone').datepicker('setDates', result);
    }
});
```

Above ajax result is like:

```
['2016-12-05','2016-12-12','2016-12-19','2016-12-26','2016-12-06','2016-12-13','2016-12-20','2016-12-27','2016-12-07','2016-12-14','2016-12-21','2016-12-28','2016-12-01','2016-12-08','2016-12-15','2016-12-22','2016-12-29','2016-12-02','2016-12-09','2016-12-16','2016-12-23','2016-12-30','2016-12-03','2016-12-10','2016-12-17','2016-12-24','2016-12-31','2016-12-04','2016-12-11','2016-12-18','2016-12-25']
```

Comment: Provide enough code please

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: How you pass data in ajax ? Where is your on click of a button code ?

Comment: @RakeshSojitra Ok wait, let me add all this

Comment: @RakeshSojitra check the updated question

Comment: What is console.log(result); ? Is it json data ?

Comment: @RakeshSojitra I posted result in question, check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125102/discussion-between-pathik-vejani-and-rakesh-sojitra).

Comment: @PathikVejani. Why would you create a `setdates` tag just for this question? I think the bootstrap-datepicker and/or jquery-multidatespicker should be sufficient to categorize . Also, please read how to create a [mcve].